# In my ActiveMQ config I have problems with the udp and http protocols

Tags: activemq-classic

In chapter 4 of the book ActiveMQ in action, you add protocols. So I did

```
<broker ...>
        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="nio" uri="nio://0.0.0.0:61617?..."/>
            <transportConnector name="udp" uri="udp://0.0.0.0:61618?..."/>
            <transportConnector name="http" uri="http://0.0.0.0:8080?..."/>
```

The nio seems to be OK, but udp and http not. If you start the server, you see,

```
 INFO | Listening for connections at: nio://walnut.nuts.org:61617?trace=true
 INFO | Connector nio started
 INFO | Connector udp started
 INFO | Connector http started
```

So no listeners with udp and http.

With upd, I see nothing.

With http, I see,

```
Exception in thread "ActiveMQ Transport: HTTP Reader http://localhost:8080" com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : input contained no data
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Is port 8080 used by any other application as well?please check

Comment: @Vihar, no, it is not

Comment: What client libraries are you using to try and connect to these transport connectors.

Comment: The examples from the book activemq in action, so a JMS publisher and consumer.